# Clicar e adicionar id no array. Se clicar de novo, remover este id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou com um problema, tenho uma lista e quando o usuário clica ele adiciona o id dessa `<li>` em um array, mas eu quero que quando ele clique de novo sobre essa `<li>`, esse id seja removido do id.
Aqui está no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r9dytj5n/1/).

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">Teste 1</li>
  <li id="2">Teste 2</li>
  <li id="3">Teste 3</li>
  <li id="4">Teste 4</li>
  <li id="5">Teste 5</li>
  <li id="6">Teste 6</li>
  <li id="7">Teste 7</li>
  <li id="8">Teste 8</li>
  <li id="9">Teste 9</li>
  <li id="10">Teste 10</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="show">Exibir selecionados</a>
<div id="retorno"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
  var idsSelecionados = [];
  $('li').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   idsSelecionados.push(id+',');
   $(this).toggleClass("active");  
  });

    $('#show').on('click', function(){
        $.each(idsSelecionados, function(i, val){
          $('#retorno').append(val);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que uma solução à pergunta é:

```
$(function(){
  var idsSelecionados = [];
  $('li').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var idx = idsSelecionados.indexOf(id+',');
   if (idx == -1) {
     idsSelecionados.push(id+',');
   } else {
     idsSelecionados.splice(idx, 1);
   }
   $(this).toggleClass("active");  
  });

    $('#show').on('click', function(){
        $.each(idsSelecionados, function(i, val){
          $('#retorno').append(val);
        });
    });
});
```

Observações:

O método `delete` pode ser utilizado para excluir o elemento do array, mas fica um "buraco"com o valor `undefined`, o método `Array.splice` não deixa este "buraco".

Como não sei por que ter colocado a vírgula junto com o `id`, deixei. Mas pode ser um equívoco durante a programação, se necessário, modificar para ficar como desejado.

Falta uma coisa que não foi objeto principal da pergunta e não tenho certeza: `toggleClass` acho que só adiciona a classe `active`, então você ainda precisa achar como retira a classe `active` e colocar essas instruções dentro do `if` e do `else`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lista = [];

$("li").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var index = lista.indexOf(id);

    if(index > -1) {
        lista.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
        lista.push(id);
    }
    $("#retorno").html(lista);
});
```